# $2D$ plane geometry inequality

Tags: geometry

I am trying to shade a region on the $2D$ plane [image]

that can satisfy

$$1-x-y \leq 0$$

What region would that be? Am I even drawing the line correct? thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Your equation also reads $y \geq 1-x$. This are all points which lie above the graph of the function $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R: x \mapsto 1-x$. (Not only those in the first quadrant as you drawd.)

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that i restrict $x$ and $y$ to positive. What would the point be in this case?

Comment: Then, indeed all points above the line you drawed. (including the line itself)